# R : Topological sort of decomposed network graph parts

Tags: r, networking, igraph, topological-sort

I am interested in creating a data frame from topological sort of various parts of decomposed network graph. My program can produce this for individual parts of the decomposed network and I get a data frame which shows nodes in proper sequence.

```
g <- graph.data.frame(Data, directed="TRUE")
dg <- decompose.graph(g)
topo <- topological.sort(dg[[1]],mode="out")
df <- ldply(topo, data.frame)
colnames(df) <- c("id","id_order")
df$activity_order <- seq.int(nrow(df))

##      id id_order activity_order
## 1   355        1              1
## 2  3180        3              2
## 3  6019        4              3
## 4 10672        2              4
## 5 49507        5              5
```

But, when I want to iterate this over all the parts of decomposed network, it does not produce the expected output.

```
Newdata <- do.call("rbind", lapply(1:clusters(g)$no, function(x){
dgpart <- dg[[x]]
topopart <- topological.sort(dgpart,mode="out")
dfpart <- ldply(topopart, data.frame)
colnames(dfpart) <- c("id","id_order")
dfpart$activity_order <- seq.int(nrow(dfpart))
}))
```

Comment: I was able to resolve this problem.